# Mobile analytics for android library

Tags: android, analytics, android-library, newrelic, flurry

I am working on android library and wondering which analytics solution would be the best for this purpose. I want to monitor:

- unique app installations / removals using my library
- memory consumption, number of background applications while doing some specific operations in my library
- crashes / exceptions
- custom events

All these statistics should be easily grouped by library version, device type, android version as well as custom tags/parameters.

I have used **Flurry** and **NewRelic** which seems to be good tools but application oriented. Is there anything recommended especially for mobile sdks/libraries meeting my requirements?

Comment: I think this is a valid question. Knowing which analytics support mobile SDK is a matter of facts and not opinions.

Answer (score 5):

New Relic is only for applications, but you could use @trace annotation for custom instrumentation of your library methods. This would require the dev using your library to also use New Relic.