# Mobile Application analytitcs

Tags: android, ios, google-analytics, analytics, flurry-analytics

I'm currently developing an SDK for both Android and iOS and want to embed analytics tools to monitor user behavior.

We found that the classic analytics tools such as Flurry, Google Analytics etc. are application oriented. and it can't be used by the SDK due to potential collision with the app analytics tools.

Is there any 3rd party analytics framework that can be used inside an SDK?

Did anyone manage to resolve the collision issues and run more than one instance of the classic analytics tools on the same app?

P.S.
[A similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25388956/mobile-analytics-for-android-library) was asked before but was closed for a reason I don't agree with.

Comment: Hi Ika, asking for third party resources, tutorials and books is considered off-topic on SO. Don't be surprised if this one gets closed as well.

Comment: Hi NSNoob, this is a relevant question for all the mobile developers that develop SDK. If you will notice there are dedicated tags in SO for flurry, google-analytics and more. The question is very focused. Is there a solution for third party analytics tools for SDK? I hope it will not be closed.

Comment: Existence of tags does not cloud the fact that it is indeed asking for 3rd party resources which is explicitly classified as off-topic. I haven't flagged it though as such due to not being well-versed in analytics myself. Just thought I should give you a heads-up. Goodluck and Cheers!

Comment: You just call the Google Analytics endpoint yourself so you do not need any library in you SDK.

Comment: Thanks rckoenes. You just solved my problem.